# How can I tell if I am running 2D or 3D Unity?

Tags: unity, 11.04, unity-2d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Am I using Unity or Unity 2D?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62001/am-i-using-unity-or-unity-2d)

I have just installed the Ubuntu 11.04 Alpha on my laptop.

How can I tell whether I have the 2D or the 3D Unity running?