# What's the visual difference between Unity 3D and Unity 2D?

Tags: unity, unity-2d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Am I using Unity or Unity 2D?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62001/am-i-using-unity-or-unity-2d)

The answer to this question ( [How can I tell if I am running 2D or 3D Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32065/how-can-i-tell-if-i-am-running-2d-or-3d-unity) ) doesn't show the visual differences between Unity 3d and 2d.

If I have followed the instructions, where can I see which Unity I'm running?