# Unity Launcher buttons size 11.10 on Samsung netbooks

Tags: 11.10, launcher, button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I configure Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity)

I've followed all the instructions in the previous questions and the size (obtrusively enormous btw) of the icons doesn't change.

What else do I need to enable/disable. It seems to a shame to switch off Unity but it seems designed to be difficult to modify.

This problem seems to exist in Samsung netbooks, and does not respond to changes made in CCSM, Confity or gconf.

Comment: If the existing config tools don't work for you you might be running Unity 2D and not knowing it, can you check here and then update your question? http://askubuntu.com/questions/39444/whats-the-visual-difference-between-unity-3d-and-unity-2d

Comment: Voting to re-open, because the edit I just approved suggested that it wasn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

- You first need to install the **Compiz Config Settings Manager** from the Ubuntu Software Center.
- Second, open Compiz Config Settings Manager and go to **Ubuntu Unity Plugin**. There under the **Experimental** tab, adjust the bar corresponding to *Launcher Icon Size* to your need.

[image: ccsm]

[image: ubuntu unity plugin - ccsm]

Comment: Unfortunately I've already did that and the icons don't change size. Are there any other plugins that I need (eg opengl) or other settings ? I'm on a Samsung netbook and the icons are too big.

Comment: Hi Jorge,no I am running Unity, not Unity 2D. I even downloaded Confity to check my settings, my icon size is down to 32 and still does not change the size of the icons on the launcher. Thanks for your time. On my normal laptop it worked perfectly and reduced the size of my icons, but on this netbook it doesn't seem to make any difference. I have performed exactly the same actions - both upgrades from 11.04.