# alt tab switcher effects not working

Tags: 11.10, unity-2d, application-switcher

Yesterday I upgraded Ubuntu from 11.04 to 11.10.

There is a nice effect of alt tab switcher with windows preview in 11.10 but with my system only simple alt tab switcher is working without effects.

I have Nvidia 1GB graphics card. I was using ubuntu classic with 11.04 as driver was not working with it but with 11.10 now nvidia driver is working and I want all unity effects.

I have installed compiz setting manager but can't able to enable alt tab switcher effects from anywhere.

Comment: Can you confirm if you're using Unity 2D or Unity 3D? more on that here - http://askubuntu.com/questions/62001/am-i-using-unity-or-unity-2d

Comment: I am using unity 3d

Comment: oh I am really sorry. I am using unity 2D. Really sorry I told you without checking your provided link. So unity 2D don't have alt tab switcher effects, right ? I think I have problem with my nvidia driver.

Comment: Ah, ok. Unity 2D *does not* have the fancy alt-tab affects unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is as follows:

It's not possible to have the super-slick <kbd>Alt-Tab</kbd> switcher because you're using Unity 2D and not 3D.