# Can't enable Unity 2D

Tags: unity, unity-2d

I've just installed Ubuntu 11.10 and have done a full update.  I have found that standard Unity is just too much for my laptop, so I thought I should enable Unity 2D from the login menu.  However, when I do enable Unity 2D, it seems to continue to load standard Unity.  Why is this happening?

How can I check if it actually has loaded Unity 2D instead of standard Unity?

Comment: It actually looks quite similar to the "3D" Unity, so it might be working correctly.

Comment: Have a look at the previously answered question here http://askubuntu.com/questions/62001/am-i-using-unity-or-unity-2d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. It's actually quite flattering to the developers of Unity 2D that it's of so high quality that you really do have difficulties noticing the difference between them.

If you're running Unity 2D, then you'll see processes like "unity-2d-launcher" in your system monitor. But a faster test is to click and drag a launcher entry. If you're using Unity, then you can pull it outside the launcher. If you're using Unity 2D, then you can only drag it up and down within the launcher.

The dash also do look a little different.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me realise that I was running Unity 2D all along. It's really slow which is why I thought that I might be running standard Unity, but I'm not... On this same laptop, Ubuntu 10.04 with the standard desktop runs very very responsive. For example, if I click on the webbrower on 10.04, it loads in about a second, on 11.10 it takes about 5 seconds... Might have to consider Lubuntu in the future as my main OS when 10.04 reaches EOL.