# How can I change Unity Dash to desktop mode

Tags: unity, 12.10, ubuntu-netbook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I resize the Unity Dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68788/how-can-i-resize-the-unity-dash)

I am using a netbook, and I noticed that pressing the <kbd>super</kbd> key, which brings up the unity dash with the lenses, is a full-screen affair. I prefer the desktop version which doesn't take up all of my screen. How do I change this?

Comment: Type this in terminal:
dconf write /com/canonical/unity/form-factor "'Desktop'"
or:
Use dConf editor and under com-canonical-unity select form-factor and change it to 'Desktop'.

Answer (score 0):

There's a *Maximize* button at the top left corner of the screen. Have you tried pressing it to unmaximize Unity Dash?

Answer (score 0):

For 12.04, I would say use MyUnity, but that isn't yet available for 12.10. Instead, use Unsettings, a beta package from Florian Diesch.

You'll need the PPA to get the package:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:diesch/testing
```

Then update and install:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unsettings
```

Launch Unsettings, then navigate to "Dash" and choose the size there.