# Why is sysinfo reporting Gnome 2 rather than Gnome 3

Tags: unity, 11.10

After upgrading from 11.04 (N.N.) to 11.10 (O.O.), I have many problems.  The first problem is that I was expecting Gnome to be updated to Gnome 3.  However, `sysinfo` reports:

```
Release: Ubuntu 11.10 (oneiric)
Gnome:   2.32.1
Kernel:  3.0.0-12-generic
```

I executed the `unity_support_test` to assure that Unity 3D is supported by my graphics hardware.  The result follows.

```
1$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
OpenGL vendor string:   ATI Technologies Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6620G
OpenGL version string:  4.1.11005 Compatibility Profile Context

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

However, I cannot discern whether `Unity 3D` is actually executing.  It looks identical to `Ubuntu 2D` (as identified on the session login screen), which I am guessing is the `Unity 2D` configuration.

My question is: Why is `sysinfo` reporting `Gnome 2` rather than `Gnome 3`?

Comment: And the question is?. This site doesn't work as a forum, long conversations are difficult (post change places). It excels at resolving questions, but I can't find your question. BTW: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62001/am-i-using-unity-or-unity-2d

Comment: If you need to install Gnome shell, do a `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`. After install logout, and select Gnome from the session selector.

Answer (score 1):

a very very easy solution (even for Ubuntu-dulls or my mother in law...who is using also ubuntu) if Ubuntu is not upgrading properly, just download 11.10, burn it on a CD and install it!!! It will detect a previous failed installation and will correct it. All installed programs and most settings are keep as original. I was surprised how well it worked when I run into a problem while upgrading. My upgrade got stuck after rebooting at 'checking battery state' due to interruption of my wireless Internet while upgrading. Hope this helps for others as well!!!