# Can I disable the alt+window+right click behaviour for editing panels in Gnome Classic?

Tags: 11.10, gnome-panel, gui, gnome-classic

In Gnome Classic 11.10, when you want to make edits to the Gnome Panel, you have to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> and then right click.

I believe in some cases it's just <kbd>Alt</kbd> and right click, but because of setting change to get Compiz to run on my machine, it became <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> and right click. I believe this is a known issue.

In any case, whether it's <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> and right click, or just <kbd>Alt</kbd> and right click, this new key combination thing is totally unneeded as far as I'm concerned. I was perfectly fine with just right clicking to edit the panel, as was the case in Gnome 2.2.

Is there a way to change this behaviour so I can edit the panel just by right clicking and not having any key combination?

Comment: But the key question was: Is it possible to work with panels without the ALT key pressed, like in Ubuntu 10.04?

Comment: @anonimal: Yes, but the short version of Anonymous's answer is "no". But at least he provided an explanation of why, and an option for what else to do. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+MouseClick is used by Compiz for moving and resizing windows, hence it conflicts with the GNOME Panel that uses <kbd>Alt</kbd>+RightClick for bringing up the context menu.

It is a conflict that occurs because both wants to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Mouse. Using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+Mouse is a workaround that prevents Compiz from capturing the key-combination and lets GNOME Panel get it.

You can remap the key-combination for Compiz to use another key than <kbd>Alt</kbd>. I remapped it to use <kbd>Super</kbd> instead.

`gconftool-2 --set --type string /apps/metacity/general/mouse_button_modifier '<Super>'`

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. Is it possible to not have any key modifier?