# "Never hide" Unity launcher via CCSM & gconf doesn't work

Tags: unity, launcher, autohide

All:
I am running Unity 3D and I want to set my launcher to never hide.  I first ran ccsm, and set "Hide Launcher" to "Never".  I rebooted then logged back in and it was still auto-hiding.

I then ran gconf-editor, I navigated to /apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options and then set launcher_hide_mode to 0.  I again rebooted and logged back in.  The launcher is still auto-hiding.

Checking gconf-editor, launcher_hide_mode is set to 0, but this setting isn't active however.

What can I do to get the launcher to Never hide?

Thanks,

Jim

Comment: are you absolutely sure that you are running unity 3d - you could be running unity 2D without knowing it... ? http://askubuntu.com/questions/62001/am-i-using-unity-or-unity-2d

Comment: Confirm version of **Ubuntu**.  eg. 11.10, 11.04 .  This Unity fix works for me (or using CCSM), and has done so for some time.

Answer (score 1):

You should run `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION` in a terminal to see what Unity version you are running. Especially when you updated your videocard drivers. Chances are something ent wrong and it falls back to 2d.

Comment: The question is about the hide behavior. Would the solution be different for 2D vs 3D?

Comment: Yes, Unity 3d (default if supported hardware/drivers) works with compiz, and Unity 2d doesn't. So changing settings in CCSM will have no effect if you are running Unity 2d.