# Disabling Unity autohide is not working

Tags: unity

I have disabled the autohide of UNITY, still Unity side bar is hiding when I am maximizing any application.

I have attached the screen shot. Right now auto hide is disabled but the left Unity bar is hidden. I am using unity3d with ATi drivers.

[image]

Any solution to disable Unity hiding will be great help.

- I have rebooted the machine. Actually, I found that any changes made through the CCSM is not affecting Unity. :(

Comment: @Jorge Castro, I am using unity3d with ATi drivers.

Comment: I think I tried this, too, but it didn't work until I restarted. You can try logging out and then back in, too.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the computer? I often have to do this in order for changes to take effect.

Comment: Yes, I have rebooted the machine. Actually, I found that any changes made through the CCSM is not affecting Unity. :(

Comment: given your statement that no CCSM changes are affecting Unity - I think you are running Unity-2D without you knowing it... see this Q&A and you can confirm this: http://askubuntu.com/a/62008/14356

Comment: Yes.. after that I checked it and I am sure I am running the UNITY-3D.Anyway I reimaged my system and now it is working fine. This is a very weired issue. thanks guys for help. Mods please close the question.