# How do I enable Unity 2D on the LiveCD?

Tags: 11.10, unity-2d, live-cd

My computer is pretty old so I'd really like to have Unity 2D enabled. Does anyone know how to do that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your computer is *old* then it is probably defaulting to unity-2d by default - this is called "fallback" mode.

To check that you are using *unity-2d* use the linked Q&A below.

If you are actually using unity-3d, then you can logout of the live CD, change session to unity 2D and then log back in.

To do this, press the Dash button and search for terminal.

force a logout by typing:

```
gnome-session-quit --logout --no-prompt
```

Change the session to "Unity-2D" by pressing the cog button.

Your username is "ubuntu" and there is no password.

---

Linked Question

1. [Am I using Unity or Unity 2D?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62001/am-i-using-unity-or-unity-2d)