# Switching to workspaces view shows buggy blue background

Tags: unity, graphics, workspaces

When switching to workspaces view everything the background turns blue.

Same happens when I switch between multiple windows of the same app too. Happening after having a try with gnome shell out of curiosity. Installed through official repos like normal. Tried it out but switched back, anyone have an idea of why this is happening?

Got an Intel GPU and Unity 3d.

Update: Looks like during the switch somehow opengl was disabled. glxinfo returns:

```
name of display: :0
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig

Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
```

This is very distressing, all I wanted to do was try out gnome3. Does anyone have an idea on how I can get opengl back?

**update**

I found out what happened. Apparently it's not that hard to accidentally install an nvidia driver. All I had to do was remove all the stuff that had nvidia in it and I got 3d back! For anyone else, this is how I found out:

check out Xorg.0.log

```
`$ cat / var/log/Xorg.0.log | more`
```

if you see a line like this somewhere

```
`(EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)`
```

you got an nvidia problem

Comment: Your screenshot actually looks like [Unity 2D](http://askubuntu.com/q/62001/18612). Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I have same problem in unity 2D
BUT NO PROBLEM UNITY 3d

Comment: Okay then it looks like while switching to gnome3 and back im now stuck on unity 2d. How do I switch back because I know for a fact that I had unity 3d to begin with. Collapsing icons and the like.

Comment: Can you add your solution as an answer then upvote it?

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding this as an answer so that the question can be closed:

Ok I found out what happened. Apparently it's not that hard to accidentally install an nvidia driver. All I had to do was remove all the stuff that had nvidia in it and I got 3d back! For anyone else, this is how I found out:

check out `Xorg.0.log`

```
$ cat / var/log/Xorg.0.log | more
```

if you see a line like this somewhere

```
(EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)
```

you got an nvidia problem.