# Why does unity 2d have compositing enabled by default?

Tags: unity-2d, compositing

Why does unity 2d have compositing enabled, doesn't that defeat the whole purpose of having a light weight unity variant?

Comment: The answer to this question may help you as a starting point, but I am sure someone will come along and give you a better response.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/62001/am-i-using-unity-or-unity-2d