# Changed some settings in Compiz - now Ubuntu freezes on startup

Tags: 12.04, unity, freeze

I just [got Unity3D working on my laptop](https://askubuntu.com/a/141969/18112), and celebrated by trying out some of the new features that weren't available to me in Unity2D.

While I was playing around with the settings for Desktop Cube and Rotate Cube, the desktop froze and I had to do a hard reboot (holding the on/off-button on my computer until it shut of, then turn it on again). Now, when I try to boot into Ubuntu, the system freezes and I can't get in.

I tried removing `quiet` and changing `splash` to `no-splash` in the grub boot script, but I didn't get any useful information because the "freezing point" was just after the Ubuntu logo and mouse shows up (I assume right after the X-server starts...?)

I've set up my computer to log me in automatically from boot, so I can't (easily) get to the login screen either, to choose "Ubuntu 2D" and login and change the failing settings (whatever they are). I can drop to root shell from boot - however, once in the root shell, I have no idea what to do to fix this problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Answer (score 1):

I tried various ways to reset the settings from a root shell, including the following:

1. `compiz --reset`
2. `unity --reset`
3. `gconftool --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1`
4. Either of the above, preceded by `su tomas`

However, none of it worked. I ended up reinstalling Ubuntu 12.04 without formatting any partitions (and making sure to select the same mount points as the ones I had before all of this happened). The installation took less than 20 minutes and could restore most of the stuff that I had from before.

Answer (score 0):

If you can open terminal then run `gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz && gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/compiz-1`. Then restart.

or

1.Boot into live cd

goto `/home/` directory in the partition **where you have installed ubuntu.**

2.remove

`~/.gconf/apps/compiz-1`

`~/.gconf/apps/compizconfig-1`

`~/.gconf/apps/metacity`

`~/.config/compiz-1`

**you must delete this folder from your home directory not home directory of your current live session**.