# 12.04 Compiz does not properly work since upgrade

Tags: unity, compiz, updates

A few days ago, I updated the kernel to `3.2.0-29-generic-pae`. Since then, all compiz effects have disappeared (all such as wobbly windows, windows switcher, workspace changing effects...).

The `unity --reset` or `compiz --replace` commands don't help as all the windows' edges/buttons vanish, the desktop background becomes black. After rebooting, I am back to a working interface, but without compiz effect.

I have tried the following solutions which have no effect on my desktop:

- [Changed some settings in Compiz - now Ubuntu freezes on startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142893/changed-some-settings-in-compiz-now-ubuntu-freezes-on-startup)
- [How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

Do you have any ideas on how I can fix this problem ? Help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you are running unity 3d by executing `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p`.

If the test passes read on, else your graphics driver need to be reinstalled.

That compiz replace changes all values to default value. In default compiz doesn't provide woobly or other effects.

Open up `ccsm` and configure the changes.

Comment: Okay, it is a graphics driver problem. I have tried a fast reinstall it did help a little, at least now I know where to look.