# How to enable unity 3d in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, unity, nvidia, graphics

I installed the graphic card driver:

[image]

But Unity is still in 2d mode:

[image]

How can I bring it into 3d mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That *is* Unity 3D (if the screenshot you posted is accurate, that is).

The 3D part simply means that it uses OpenGL (it doesn't mean it's literally 3D).

Comment: But according http://askubuntu.com/questions/62001/am-i-using-unity-or-unity-2d it's not 3d!!!panel icons have background and I don't have a smooth animations...

Comment: @Mohammad, Yes, panel icons _do_ have a background in Unity 3D (I can confirm this), and the reason why you don't have smooth animations is that your computer and/or graphics card is slower (well, TBH, it's technically unity's fault, but I won't get into that). Also, look at the dash. It has NONE of the features in Unity 2D (therefore, it's unity 3D).