# How to tell if 13.04 will run slowly on my computer

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, graphics, hardware, 13.04

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit and when I try to upgrade to 12.10 I see an error saying that my computer will run slowly.


[image]


If I upgrade to 12.10 and then 13.04 will my computer still run slow or will 13.04 run on my computer smoothly.  I have an IBM thinkpad T42 with a 1.7 GHz processor and 1 gig of Ram.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would add to your question what hardware  prompts this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason for this is that "Unity 2d" is removed in 12.10, and if you don't have proper graphics support (or a really good processor) Unity3D will run slow.

This is because Unity3D will be running through LLVMpipe, which basically runs all the graphics on the main processor.

The [website mentioned on the error box](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Bugs/UpdateManagerWarningForUnity3D) states:

> If you choose to continue anyway, Ubuntu will try to run using
>   software rendering (via LLVMpipe). While llvmpipe is pretty good on
>   modern CPUs, if your video card is old your CPU is likely old too, and
>   it may result in unusable performance.
>
> Alternatives may include sticking with an old ubuntu release or
>   switching to one of the lighter weight derivatives or Debian. For
>   12.04 and 12.10, ubuntu-classic (no effects) is also a feasible option. To do this, install the gnome-session-fallback package, and
>   then on the login screen click the gear icon and select
>   "Ubuntu-classic (no effects)".

How to tell if your are running the 2d or 3d: [Am I using Unity or Unity 2D?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62001/am-i-using-unity-or-unity-2d)

If you are running 3D currently I may mean that the new drivers don't support the card on your machine, or if there is a chance of getting graphics drivers working it probably won't be easy, and these problems will likely continue in 13.04.

So probably the best options:

- Stick with 12.04 (still use the version of unity you are using)
- Or, Move to Xubuntu, Kubuntu, Lubuntu and upgrade (other desktops, will not look like unity)